# convert to rxjs methodology

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to convert the following 2 methods to rxjs methodology. How can i do that. The second method depends upon the results of the first.

```
export class EntityStorage {
  private entitiesStore: Map<string, any[]> = new Map<string, any[]>();

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  loadAllEntity(key: string, httpParams: HttpParams): void {
    this.apiService.getEntities(key, httpParams).subscribe(
      (entities) => {
        this.entitiesStore.set(key, entities);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
      () => {}
    );
  }

  getStoreWithKey(key: string): any[] {
    return this.entitiesStore.get(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
export class EntityStorage {
  private setEntities = new Subject<[string, any[]]>();
  private entitiesStore = new ReplaySubject<Map<string, any[]>>(1)

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {

    this.setEntities.pipe(
      scan((entityMap, [key, entities]) => {
        entityMap.set(key, entities);
        return entityMap;
      }, new Map<string, any[]>())
    ).subscribe(this.entitiesStore)

  }

  loadAllEntity(key: string, httpParams: HttpParams): void {
    this.apiService.getEntities(key, httpParams).subscribe(
      (entities) => {
        this.setEntities.next([key, entities]);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
      () => {}
    );
  }

  getStoreWithKey(key: string): any[] {
    return this.entitiesStore.pipe(
      map(entityMap => entityMap.get(key)), 
      filter(entity => !!entity), // optional, prevent emissions until key loaded.
      distinctUntilChanged() // optional. prevents subscribers from receiving updates about different keys.
    );
  }
}
```

basically you use a private local subject to trigger updates to your map replay subject and leverage scan to make updates to it.

if you wanted to, could even move the load into the stream which would give finer control over loading, ie, not calling the entity load twice for the same key (if that's possible in your app), let me know if that's needed.

Comment: Good choice moving to a `ReplaySubject`. One of the benefits of doing so is that you no longer need the ugly `filter`. I suggest removing that, too.

Comment: you still need the filter.... it prevents emission prior to KEY being loaded, switch to ReplaySubject just eliminates potentially one random emission and the need to initialzie

Comment: Ah, I missed the `distinctUntilChanged`.

Comment: distinctUntilChanged has a different purpose, ensuring subscribers to a given key don't get updates about changes to other keys.

Comment: @bryan60 ([key, entities], entityMap) gives me error info  Type 'Map<string, any[]>' is not assignable to type '[string, any[]]'.

Comment: slight typo, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but should work.

Note that subscribers will emit after each call to `loadAllEntity`, so consider using `take(1)` to ignore further updates.

```
export class EntityStorage {
    private $entitiesStore = new ReplaySubject<Map<string, any[]>>();
    private entitiesStore: Map<string, any[]> = new Map<string, any[]>();

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

    loadAllEntity(key: string, httpParams: HttpParams): void {
        this.apiService.getEntities(key, httpParams).subscribe(
            (entities) => {
                this.entitiesStore.set(key, entities);
                this.$entitiesStore.next(this.entitiesStore);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            },
            () => {}
        );
    }

    getStoreWithKey(key: string): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.$entitiesStore.pipe(
            map((entitiesStore) => entitiesStore.get(key))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this will erase any previously set keys on each load.

Comment: @bryan60 Sure, it will, but since the function is called `loadAllEntity`, I assumed this is the behaviour OP wants.

Comment: the code implies it's loading all entities for a given key and the map stores multiple keys. otherwise not much point in a map

Comment: Bit ambiguous, but sure, it could be intended to work that way also. All OP has to do is keep the class level `entitiesStore` if that's the case.

Comment: not if he wants subscribers to be aware of changes to the map

Comment: @RichardDunn Thank you for your support. I don't want to destroy map values for others keys other than one in action. Doing new Map inside load i believe will destroy values from other keys too.

Comment: @bryan60 It's a `ReplaySubject`, they will get notified.

Comment: probably want to set the replay subject to 1 emission. otherwise new subscribers will get every update ever made to the store upon subscription